# objC Preprocessor NSString Macro

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, c-preprocessor

I have a problem to create a preprocessor macro function, that concatenates two Strings and "return" a `NSString` (@"...") value.

Here is what I tried:

```
#define ObjectKeyMake(NAME) @"com.test.##NAME"
```

if I print the result from a call I get:

```
NSLog(@"%@", ObjectKeyMake(foo)); // com.test.##NAME
```

**so my question is**: How can i concatenate 2 Strings in a preprocessor macro and "return" a NSString (@"..") ?

and no I can't use `#define ObjectKeyMake(NAME) [@"com.test." stringByAppendingString: NAME]` because i need a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the compiler combines string literals that are next to each other, like this:

```
NSString* greeting = @"Hello, " "world";
```

The macro implementation would look like this:

```
#define ObjectKeyMake(NAME) (@"com.test." #NAME)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define ObjectKeyMake(NAME) @"com.test."#NAME
```